# Find the limit as z goes to 0 for the function Im(z)/z (complex analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

$\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} \frac{\mathrm{Im}(z)}{z}$

This question deals with complex analysis so if anyone has knowledge on this subject, I would be so grateful. My best guess is to substitute z as $\mathrm re^{i\theta}$ and go from there but I am unsure how.

Comment: We have
$$\frac{\text{Im(z)}}{z} = \frac{r\sin\theta}{re^{i \theta}} = \sin(\theta) e^{-i\theta}. $$

Comment: That makes sense @Falcon! So if z goes to 0, would that translate to $\theta$ going to 0 as well? Hence making the rest of the limit go to 0, too?

Comment: No, the quotient does not depend on $r$ i.e. the quotient is equal to $\sin (\theta) e^{-i\theta} $ for all $r \in \mathbb R$, thus also for $r \to 0$.